# Decompilation multiple Dlls

Tags: .net, decompiler, reflector

I have a directory with multiple .Net libraries (+/- 500 dlls).
I need decompile this libraries to obtain the C# sourcecode. 
I use .Net Reflector software to decompile each library, but I should select each library one to one.

Is there any method which can decompile all libraries into directory easily? Any other tool?

Clarification: I don't need open all Dlls from a directory. I need 'export' the sourcecode from multiple Dlls without I must select one to one.

Comment: Be aware that some times the code generated by reflector/similar tools isn't directly compilable... If you really have 500 dlls, you have weeks of work to make the decompiled code work.

Comment: Thansk. I dont need compile the sourcecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an addin to do that a while back. You can get the Dll [here](http://jasonhaley.com/files/Reflector.OpenDirectory.DllOnly.zip) or the source code [here](http://jasonhaley.com/files/Reflector.OpenDirectory.Source.zip)

It adds an item to the File menu that opens a Folder Browser and will add all .net assemblies found in that directory to the assembly browser.

There's a little more information about it on the Reflector form [here](http://forums.reflector.net/questions/3976/start-net-reflector-with-list-of-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I don't need open all Dlls into a directory. I need 'export' the sourcecode from multiple Dlls without I must select one to one.

Comment: Ah, sorry I guess I missed that point.  It would probably take around 4 hours of coding but it can be done using Reflector.  2 options - either use an addin to do it or wrap reflector and write your own code to do it.  If I get any extra time in the next couple of weeks I could do it for you.  Otherwise you should look at Jason Bock's project that decompiled dlls to source code (http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/codefilegenerator.aspx)